# How to use Javascript's for (attr in this) with Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

In Javascript, the "for (attr in this)" is often dangerous to use... I agree.  That's one reason I like Coffeescript.  However, I'm programming in Coffeescript and have a case where I need Javascript's "for (attr in this)".  Is there a good way to do this in Coffeescript?

What I am doing now is writing a bunch of logic in embedded raw Javascript, such as:

```
...coffeescript here...
for (attr in this) {
  if (stuff here) {
    etc
  }
}
```

It'd be nice to use as little Javascript as possible... any suggestions for how I can achieve this and maximize my use of Coffeescript?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of `for item in items` which iterates through arrays, you can use `for attr, value of object`, which works more like `for in` from JS.

```
for own attr, value of this
  if attr == 'foo' && value == 'bar'
    console.log 'Found a foobar!'
```

Compiled: https://gist.github.com/62860f0c07d60320151c

It accepts both the key and the value in the loop, which is very handy.  And you can insert the `own` keyword right after the `for` in order to enforce an `if object.hasOwnProperty(attr)` check which should filter out anything from the prototype that you don't want in there.

Comment: Exactly right. CoffeeScript's `for...of` compiles directly to JavaScript's `for...in`. CoffeeScript's `for...in` is for iterating over the values in arrays, strings, and other zero-indexed structures with a `length` property.

Answer (score 6):

Squeegy's answer is correct. Let me just amend it by adding that the usual solution to JavaScript's `for...in` being "dangerous" (by including prototype properties) is to add a `hasOwnProperty` check. CoffeeScript can do this automatically using the special `own` keyword:

```
for own attr of this
  ...
```

is equivalent to the JavaScript

```
for (attr in this) {
  if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(this, attr)) continue;
  ...
}
```

When in doubt about whether you should use `for...of` or `for own...of`, it's generally safer to use `own`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for x in y` or `for x of y` depending on how you want to interpret a list of elements. The newest version of CoffeeScript aims to solve this problem, and you can read about its new use with an issue (that has since been implemented and closed) [here on GitHub](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/436)

Comment: awesome. `for x of y` does exactly what the OP was asking for!